Sparse disk image error 'No space left on device' while limit not reached
I created a sparse disk image of 400 GB with hdiutil command on an empty 500 GB external drive.
After I have attached the disk image, I copy data to it. After about 17 GB of data I get an error stating:
No space left on device

Why is it that I cannot fully utilize the 400 GB and is it raising this error?
hdiutil create -size 400g -type SPARSE -fs APFS -volname test /Volumes/data/test.dmg
hdiutil attach /Volumes/data/test.dmg.sparseimage


Any help much appreciated!




Welcome to Ask Different.  What’s your goal here, bigger picture? Do you need a volume that can shrink and doesn’t pre-allocate space? Do you need to “fix” this or can things be thrown away to test and try different settings? I think APFS can do everything you might possibly need better than a disk image can,  but I’d like to confirm what your end result is before answering.

@bmike : I need to have a disk image for a specific reason and a volume that is ultimately the size of the data copied into it (no pre-allocated space). So I want to try to solve this.

In your question, you have posted commands. The hdiutil create -size 400g -type SPARSE -fs APFS -volname test /Volumes/data/test.dmg command creates the test.dmg.sparseimage file. How was the test.dmg file created? This file is used in the hdiutil attach /Volumes/data/test.dmg command.

Where did the /Volumes/Robertico/test.dmg.sparseimage file come from? How is this file related to the /Volumes/data/test.dmg.sparseimage file?

@DavidAnderson : I have corrected my question. Sorry for the wrong command. it's hdiutil attach /Volumes/data/test.dmg.sparseimage. The hdiutil create -size 400g -type SPARSE -fs APFS -volname test /Volumes/data/test.dmg command creates the test.dmg.sparseimage file.

What data are you copying to the sparse disk image?

@DavidAnderson : All kind of files

@Robertico have you used the raw external drive before, without the disk image? Can you copy more than ~17 GB to it? If not, your drive may be defective (or a fake).

@DavidAnderson Apologies. You are absolutely right. I deleted my old comment and created a new one

@At0micMutex Disk is fine. Not defective or fake
